# Geometry nodes - Float Curve with values greater then 0..1

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'm want to cull points by distance with **Hit Distance parameter** on **Raycast node**. Everything is okay, but i want to integrate **Curves widget** to manipulate gradient dencity more accurate

[Camera Culling with Distance Culling.blend](https://pasteall.org/blend/d3b1454942034eeeabab685ae84a24b2)

[image]

Something like this, but with curve widget and smooth transition
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured that out. (Sort of..) (Sorry that I can't describe my own question clearly)
So, **Curve Floats** works with 0..1 float values by default, yes - you can tweak clipping parameter, but that would not be that handy
So it's better to convert your values (for example 0..100) to 0..1 with map range:

[image]

I used it twice: to convert to 0..1 and then turn it back, but you need to know the **Max value**

So now i have more precise control for my gradient ^-^ :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you want it, but this works for me:

[image]

[image]

or RGB curve:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Sadly Curve manipulating has strange behavior for my task
I want to have gradient of point relatively to my camera (for performance)